# How to put DOUBLE with decimal place to JSONObject? ex:- 34.0

Tags: java, android

using JSONObject to send to web service when we put double (round number) the zero and the point gets removed

```
    JSONObject ctx = new JSONObject();
    try {
        ctx.put("csrf", vfModel.getCsrf());
        ctx.put("vid", vid);
        ctx.put("ns", "");
        ctx.putOpt("ver",BigDecimal.valueOf(34.0));
        
       } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e(TAG, "JSONException null generateToken: " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

Output

```
{"csrf":"VmpFPSxNakF5TVMwd01pMHhNbFF4TXpveE16b3pNaTQ1TkRSYSwwVUVJT3kycmh6SGRYY01EZ1BWR1I3LE0yTmtaV1V6","vid":"06690000005lUNp","ns":"","ver":34}
```

Comment: So? It's still the same *number*. --- Oh, right, the value is not a "number", but a "version", which could also be something like `24.1.3`, which is very obviously not a number, but a **`String`**, so maybe `putOpt("ver", "34.0")` would work better.

Comment: Okay, but i need to put only a float number not string. when i put 34.1 then its working fine but i need to put only 34.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There’s too much to worry about in that code.

1. Of course the point gets removed. As a `double`, `34` and `34.0` are indistinguishable.
2. Never use the `Bigdecimal(double)` constructor unless you know exactly what you are doing. The `BigDecimal` can only ever be as good as the argument you pass in. But precision is lost when converting the number you typed into a double to pass as argument to the constructor. Use `BigDecimal(String)` instead.
3. `ver` looks like it should be a version number. If it is, `BigDecimal` is not the type you should be using unless you are 100% sure that you can live with the restrictions it brings (like not being able to call a release "34.0.1").

If you understand everything I write above and still want to use `BigDecimal`, use `new BigDecimal("34.0")`.

Comment: Thanks, but its not working. 

ctx.putOpt("ver",new BigDecimal("34.0"));
output -> 34

Comment: @PrinceAuthenticode Because the *number* `34.0` is the same as *number* `34`. If the trailing `.0` is **significant**, then the value is not a *number*, but a *string*.

Comment: @Andreas yes, but also not really. `new BigDecimal(34.0)` has a scale of 0, `new BigDecimal("34.0")` has a scale of 1. Thus `new BigDecimal(34.0).toString -> "34"` and `new BigDecimal("34.0") -> "34.0"` (just try using jshell). This rather looks like a glitch in either the JSON spec or in the particular JSON lib used. I once found a similar bug in a JSON lib that I used: Bigdecimals smaller than a certain value were output as doubles thus loosing precidon. But BigDecimal is the wrong type for a version string anyway.

Comment: @Axel No glitch. The library renders the `BigDecimal` as a *number*, not as a *string*, which means that trailing decimal zeros are removed, and that is perfectly valid for a **number**. As I already said, if trailing zeros are *significant*, then it is not a *number*, and you're doing it wrong, and should change the code to render the value as a *string*, where the value will be formatted exactly as you specify yourself.

Comment: @Andreas I think it depends on the library. If it doesn't claim to support BigDecimal, it's ok. But if it does, I expact when using the same library to write a BigDecimal a and read it back again into another BigDecimal b that `a.equals(b)` is fullfilled (which is perfectly possible because JSON allows use of trailing zeroes). Some libraries support BigDecimal, some don't, some had it and later removed it, and others have support that is simply broken in this respect.

Comment: @Axel In order to remove the trailing zeroes, it has to understand and support `BigDecimal`, so the library does fully support it. There is nothing in the JSON Specification ([RFC 7159](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159#section-6)) that mandates a certain format for a **number**, e.g. the following are all valid JSON Numbers for the same numeric value: `34`, `34.0`, `34.000`, `34e+0`, `34.00e+0`, `3.4e+1`, `3.400e+1`, `3400e-2`, ... The library is free to format the number as it sees fit, as long as it follows the JSON Specification.

Comment: The fact that `BigDecimal` considers the *scale* to be significant, is a flaw of `BigDecimal`.

Comment: I hope it is OK for me to disagree on both your arguments. I like BigDecimal the way it is. Next you say that IEEE754 is also flawed because it has signed zeroes where there can be only one.